# Browser history with iframes on page

Tags: iframe, back-button

I have a page with some links and a few iframes. When the user clicks on any link the content is loaded in iframes. Now I want to integrate it with browser back button. In order to achieve this what I am doing is when any link is clicked I change the window location hash and then listens for onhashchange event. When the event fires, it is handled and looking at the hash value I(restore the state and) load the content in iframes. For loading the content in iframe I use window.location.replace() method to prevent it from appearing in the history and interfere with working of back button. Is there a better approach that can be taken to achieve the above functionality? Please note that removing iframe is **NOT** an option. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the iFrame's history? As it is a seperate context and it's own web browser in a way, it has it's own history.

Try:

```
document.getElementById('id_Of_ Iframe').contentWindow.history.back();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a button like this

```
input type="button" onClick="history.back()" Value="Back"
```

Hope it will help.